# ClassNotFoundException on maven with IntelliJ

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jersey

I've been working on Google App Engine for the last 6 months on eclipse, but I am trying to go for IntelliJ now since I work a lot with android studio and I am much more familiar.

So I created a test app just for learning purposes and I got stuck with this error. (https://pastebin.com/YgB0j6TW)

The ways I started was by creating an App Engine Project, and then by "Add framework support..." adding maven. Before adding Maven I add no errors.

The dependency shown by the errors is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TestApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>  <!-- App Engine Standard currently requires Java 7 -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I've declared jersey servlets just as I did on eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">

    <display-name>TestApp</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/secret/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing.type</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value> <!-- This is a debug utility that should be disabled when code goes to production -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have checked the scope of every import and it is set to "compile". I've declared jersey servlets just as I did on eclipse.

I think this has something to do with the class path declaration which I didnt found anything wrong by chencking the solutions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve this. When using eclipse it asks to select the "war" folder so when you run it locally it updates the lib folder.

On IntelliJ it doesn't happen. That is why it was not finding the maven imported libs.

I solved it by going to [Project Structure] -> [Artifacts] -> [Output Layout] -> [WEB-INF]

The right click on the lib folder (if it exists, otherwise create it), and select "Add copy of..." -> "Library Files"

Just select the libs you need and click apply.